# Is function $f(x,y)=2x+3y$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is function

$f(x,y)=2x+3y$

linear?

If it is linear, how can I prove that this is linear(superposition, homogeneity)?

I don't know how to prove linearity of more than two variable function.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/jacobian/v/local-linearity-for-a-multivariable-function

Comment: You may use $\LaTeX$ to help your formula much easier to view.

Comment: Look up the definition for *linear maps*. You will maybe occur some terms you don’t know yet. But maybe you can understand nonetheless the gist of it. Then think about your situation. What do you think it means for $f$ to be linear? Then come back and state your thoughts.

Comment: @k.stm It has to satisfy $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1) + f(x_2)$ and $f(cx)=cf(x)$ in order to $f$ to be linear. Then for the multi-variable function, is it correct that it needs to satisfy superposition and homogeneity principle for its each variables?

Comment: @k.stm Like this if $f$ is two variable function? $f(x_1+x_2, y)=f(x_1, y) + f(x_2, y)$, $f(cx, y)=cf(x, y)$,  $f(x, y_1+y_2)=f(x, y_1) + f(x, y_2)$, $f(x, cy)=cf(x, y)$

Comment: I'm confused because I learned only the conditions of linearity of one variable function. $f(x1+x2)=f(x1)+f(x2)$  and $f(cx)=cf(x)$. How can these two conditions apply for the functions of more than one variable?

Answer (score 2):

You have to show that

$$f((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2))=f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)$$

and

$$f(c(x,y))=cf(x,y).$$

($c$ is a scalar.)